# How to "scroll" a clip so that it stays the same length but shows a different part of original video?

Tags: video, final-cut-pro

Analogy: the clip as viewed in the timeline is actually a window, behind which the entire original clip lies.

I want to move the original clip side-to-side behind this window, so that the window's size and position don't change, but it shows a different part of the original clip.

---

I have imported 3 videos into final cut pro. Each video is, on its own, at least 20 minutes long, but I've cut them all to be 15 minutes, 5 seconds, 5 minutes in order. There are "straight" (the most basic) cuts to transition from one to the next (i.e., nothing fancy).

The second clip, in-between the two other clips, is the right length but I'd like to show a different part of its video. I.e., instead of the 5 seconds it's currently showing, the first 5 seconds of that video (the original video that was imported), I'd like it to show a 5 second clip from the middle of that video.

Is there a way I can do this easily?

In my real project the timeline is full of audio and some other videos so I don't want to stretch, re-cut, delete etc. the middle video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose the Trim tool (T) and drag the clip along the timeline. The start and end points remain fixed on the timeline and the clip moves within, up to the start/end point of the clip, denoted by red markers.

Comment: Nice it was that simple! Interestingly audio aligned with the clip also scrolls when doing this.

Comment: Just to add that your trim tool cursor should be aimed at the middle of the clip, and then dragged to get your ripple. Don't inadvertently trim the beginning or end points.

Comment: What if the end point is the end of the video? How can I make it reduce the video's length

Comment: @theonlygusti Then you just want to trim the video, use the standard arrow tool or trim tool and drag the left edge of the cut to the right.